# What photo sharing sites allow frequent re-uploading from Lightroom in the background?

Tags: lightroom, sharing, publishing

I often find myself wanting to re-upload images shared online, for example after tweaking their develop settings or adding new keywords.

Some sharing services only allow new uploads or limited re-uploads that will remove visitors' existing comments from the replaced photos (a policy that has its justifications). I am looking for something that will simply replace the shared photos with their updated versions while leaving all context in place and without presenting them as new photos.

Flickr partly offers this option and I have used it with and without Jeffrey Friedl's Lightroom [plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/flickr). However, I am still finding re-uploading photos a pain as Flickr's photostream treats replacements like new uploads, i.e. any re-uploads appear at the top of the stream every time.

Short of creating one's own personal website, what solutions exist currently?

Comment: I know the OP specifically stated "short of creating one's own personal website", but for others, check out [Koken](http://koken.me/). Koken includes a Lightroom plugin which provides uploading and more importantly in-place re-uploading of images direct from Lightroom.

Answer (score 2):

Smugmug has a lightroom plugin that is excellent, and I know of no restrictions on how often an image can be replaced, in place.  It is not a free solution but it is a very solid one that is not very expensive; it also supports custom domains (varies by plan you pick).  I think most of their competitors work the same (e.g. zenfolio) though I have not used them.  The lightroom plugin is smart enough to upload just metadata changes (for example if you change a caption) without sending the whole image, and also to know when you change the image itself and schedule for upload (you do have to push the "publish" button to start the upload when ready, but it can queue thousands of images to send in background).  [I have no affiliation with SM other than as a customer.]

Answer (score 0):

What you ought to look into is using a publish service rather than an export service where you have to manually upload things. Flickr supports that through Friedl's plug-in, and it automates that reupload/update cycle very nicely with little hassle.

Comment: The OP is hoping for a Publish service/hosting site that does not trigger the "recently changed/recently uploaded" decision that the hosting site *may* make when you replace one of your renditions via the service. The Flickr API does not, AFAIK, expose any way of suppressing this, and even Friedl wasn't sure if this happens with his plugin (I actually don't recall if it does).

Comment: In my experience using it, If you use the publish channel and update an image, it'll be uploaded in place and not show it as new or changed. Any hard links to existing versions will 404, but that's part of Flickr's design and no way around it.

Comment: Yes, the fact that Flickr generates a new ID for the photo is a little annoying, but livable. As for Flickr showing re-uploads via the Publish service as new, I think this is definitely something that happens (as the OP suggests). Once upon a time there were upload/reupload behaviour differences based on if you were a "pro" user or not. If you are a pro user, this might explain things. Or, they have changed behaviour recently. Or something else.